# How to do a rolling mean of numpy array objects in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like below:

```
data = {'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05'], 'Data1': [np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([2,3,4,5]), np.array([3,4,5,6]), np.array([4,5,6,7]), np.array([5,6,7,8])]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I want to bin Data1 column with a bin size of 3 (days). Then I want to take the mean of the binned numpy arrays along axis 0.

I tried the following, but it throws a `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

```
binned_data = df["Data1"].rolling(window=3).apply(np.mean(np.array(s), axis=0))
```

The expected outcome is:

```
0 2020-01-01 [1,2,3,4]
1 2020-01-02 [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
2 2020-01-03 [2,3,4,5]
3 2020-01-04 [3,4,5,6]
4 2020-01-05 [4,5,6,7]
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Corralien updated the question with the expected output.

Comment: Do you know if you have missing dates or all are continuous?

Comment: @Corralien All are continuous

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` to compute the rolling mean with [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

window = 3

arr = np.vstack(df['Data1']).astype(float)
arr = np.pad(arr, [(window-1, 0), (0, 0)], constant_values=np.nan)

binned_data = np.nanmean(swv(arr, (window, arr.shape[1])), axis=2).squeeze()
```

Output:

```
>>> binned_data
array([[1. , 2. , 3. , 4. ],
       [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5],
       [2. , 3. , 4. , 5. ],
       [3. , 4. , 5. , 6. ],
       [4. , 5. , 6. , 7. ]])

>>> arr
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan],  # <- pad to have the same output shape
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]])

>>> swv(arr, (window, arr.shape[1]))
array([[[[nan, nan, nan, nan],  # first row [1. , 2. , 3. , 4. ]
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]]],


       [[[nan, nan, nan, nan],  # second row [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
         [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
         [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],  # third row [2. , 3. , 4. , 5. ]
         [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
         [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]]],


       [[[ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],  # fourth row [3. , 4. , 5. , 6. ]
         [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.]]],


       [[[ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],  # fifth row [4. , 5. , 6. , 7. ]
         [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
         [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]]]])
```

**Assumptions**:

1. All dates are continuous.
2. All arrays have the same length

Comment: This is great. But I am looking for a solution within Pandas. Is there a way with Pandas?

Comment: Unfortunately, as you already understood, you can't aggregate on non numeric columns.

Comment: @PasHer. Have you found a solution all this time?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `numpy`? A large part of Pandas uses Numpy behind the scenes. You can use a python loop to slice your dataframe and emulate rolling behavior but it will be slow and not efficient. Numpy is a good candidate here.